# Frontend with access only to the backend - how do you approach this kind of problem?

Tags: node.js, azure, amazon-s3, backend

Basically, the frontend of the application will be behind APIM, meaning that no request to the global internet can be made from the frontend - only to our backend. It creates a lot of problems, because the application uses CosmosDB and Azure Blob Storage, but we cannot use any direct URI to the resources located there as everything must be served by our backend.

Have you ever encountered such an architecture? I am not a DevOps expert myself, so it's pretty hard for me to answer it, but is it a good approach? I understand puttin backend behind this 'firewall', but the frontend?

How would you serve the photos allocated in Azure Blob Storage/Amazon S3 in that case? Tried to download stuff on the backend, then convert images to Base64 format and then send it to the frontend, but the queries are pretty big because of that! With the text files the thing is pretty easy, but how to handle big files, such as .pdf, .pngs etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your setup but assuming that your frontend and backed are i Azure, a standard way to do this is:

- The front end is on its own VNET
- The front end VNET allows incoming traffic from the internet
- The backend is on its own VNET
- The backend VNET allows incoming traffic only from the front end VNET

What you are missing is that the front end VPN must be allowed to talk to Cosmos DB / Blob Storage. This is done by configuring a service end point. See https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/blog/virtual-network-service-endpoints-for-azure-cosmos-db-is-now-generally-available/

If you want to get data from Amazon S3 without going over the open internet you could use a VPN.